# Обработка Файла в POST запросе в PHP

Tags: php, ziparchive

Доброго времени суток!

Я настраиваю интеграцию с 1С и возникла следующая проблема:

Я обрабатываю получение zip файла с 1С. Я должен считать с него файл обработать и дать ответ.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_status = $zip->open(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

В php://input приходит сай файл.

Но когда пытаюсь его открыть `$zip->open` то он возвращает false т.е не удалось открыть.

Может я как то не так обрабатываю получение архива? Кто подскажет как это сделать правильно?

ПСЫ: Когда в php://input приходил файл xml 
      `file_get_contents('php://input')`
 отрабатывал как надо и получал содержимое файла.

Comment: ph://input это поток, ну и пост запрос может быть ограничен размером

Comment: Архив весит несколько килобайт. Я же говорю ошибка когда он пытается его открыть. Возможно не правильно передаю или принимаю архив. Возможно нужно как то по особенному его принимать.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/ziparchive.open.php так смотри в ман 1-й параметр путь а не содержимое попробуй так `$zip->open('php://input')`

Comment: И так тоже пробовал. Тоже такая же ошибка открытия.

Comment: `$zip->open` вроде бы возвращает код ошибки, что бы указать какая именно ошибка

Comment: пробовали в файл сохранить и посмотреть что там? и отдать сам файл

Comment: @Bookin спасибо. Как узнаю что там приходило отпишусь)